# Separation of variables and condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the diff eq by separation of variables then plug in the condition.

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime} = (x + y + 1)/(x + y - 1),\,\, y(0) = 1
\end{align*}

I separated and integrated to obtain $y(y-2) = x^2 + 2x$

What exactly is the point of the condition given and how do I use it here because when I plug it in, both sides don't equal.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add constant C of indefinite integration. Just add C to RHS and find the value of C by putting x=0 & y=1. You will get C=-1.

Put value of C in original equation to get the correct solution.

Hope this will be helpful!

Comment: However, your solution to this differential equation is wrong. It would be nice if you could post your workings so that we can identify where you have made the error.